# Session-based ASP.NET Core 6 Web API login giving 404 error on [Authorize] endpoint, what could be the issue?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, session, asp.net-web-api, session-cookies

I'm adding a session-based user login system to the backend of my ASP.NET Core 6 (Web API) project. I got it set up and when testing with postman, my login endpoint gives back a session cookie and it's stored. When I then try to hit a GET endpoint decorated with the `[Authorize]` attribute, it gives a 404.

Previous to this I had set up a JWT-based system, and when a token wasn't included with a request, it'd give me a 401 or 402 as expected, so I don't know why it's giving me 404 now with the Session setup. I confirmed the endpoint works fine when the `[Authorize]` attribute is removed. My code is set up like this:

**Program.cs**

```
// Identity services
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => {})
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApiDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();


// Session tokens
builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.Name = "SessionCookie";
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddCookie();


// Further down after builder.Build()

app.UseSession();

app.UseAuthentication();  // MUST come before UseAuthorization()
app.UseAuthorization();
```

**BrDataServiceController.cs**

```
namespace BrDataService.Controllers
{
    //[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
    //[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api")]
    public class BrDataServiceController : Controller
    {
        private BrSubmitFormService _sf;

        public BrDataServiceController(IConfiguration config, BrSubmitFormService sf)
        {
            _sf = sf;
        }
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [Authorize]
        [HttpGet("Apply")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Get()
        {
            string token = HttpContext.Session.GetString("SessionToken");
            string cookie = HttpContext.Session.GetString("SessionCookie");
            Console.WriteLine("SessionToken: " + token);
            Console.WriteLine("SessionCookie: " + cookie);
            return View();
        }

...
```

You can see I experimented with using the [Authorize] attribute at the top (at the Controller level) instead, but it seems to make no difference vs. the one directly on the method.

I suspect maybe there's something going on behind the scenes involving the Authorize attribute itself, especially since the GET seems to work (and print those lines to the console, albeit the token and cookie variables are empty) when the attribute is removed; and since this all worked fine when I was using the JWT implementation, including when the Authorize attribute was present.

**What I expected**
I expected at least a 401 or 402 code, if there was perhaps something wrong with my implementation of the session cookies, but not a 404. It acts as if the endpoint doesn't even exist as long as the Authorize attribute is there.

Comment: Going off a limb here, but you can get a 404 while using the authorize attribute if your redirect / view doesn't exist. Does your View for Get() actually exist?

Comment: How are you calling this endpoint?

Comment: @kasprdev potentially good catch... no it doesn't. I just tried commenting out the return line and changed the return type, but it still gives a 404 unfortunately

Comment: Could you post all the urls that are requested during the request (may be there is a redirect involved-)?

Comment: @SalmanA first I POST a username & password to http://localhost:5000/api/Auth/Login, which gives me a session cookie & token etc. Then I GET http://localhost:5000/api/Apply, which seems to return 404 regardless of whether I do the login or not.

Answer (score 1):

You have mentioned that your view for `Get()` does not exist, and this is likely the reason you are receiving a 404 error.
When you return `View()`, ASP.NET is trying to find a view with the name of your action method (`Get` in this case). If it cannot find a view with that name, it will return a 404 error.

For testing, if you do not have a view, try returning a different ActionResult, like `Ok()` or `Content()`, and see if that resolves the issue.

```cs
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
[HttpGet("Apply")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Get()
{
    string token = HttpContext.Session.GetString("SessionToken");
    string cookie = HttpContext.Session.GetString("SessionCookie");
    Console.WriteLine("SessionToken: " + token);
    Console.WriteLine("SessionCookie: " + cookie);
    
    // If no view, return a simple string or status code
    // return Ok("Authorized");
    // or
    return Content("Authorized");
}
```

Comment: Good idea, but I tried it & got the same result. Still just a 404 no error code or anything

Comment: @jDally987 Is your application configured to provide detailed error messages? This can help in identifying the issue. 

In your `Program.cs` file, you can temporarily enable detailed errors by adding the following line:

`app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();`
Place this line before `app.UseAuthentication()` and `app.UseAuthorization()`. (only be used during development though, as it can expose sensitive information).

Answer (score 0):

that's because the cookie trying to redirect to Account/Login action as a default action and can't find it
try this one

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddCookie(options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = "ur action to handle the unauthorized users e.g 
    UserAuth/Login";
});
```